# Error: DisconnectedContext was Detected in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am facing a problem while uploading an excel sheet using oledb. Couple of weeks ago, it was working perfectly so I moved to different module.

But when I am testing and debugging the application now it is throwing an error.

Someone please look into this as I am not able to resolve this issue, also, their is no resolution posted when I searched on google as well....

> Error: DisconnectedContext was Detected
>
> Transition into COM context 0x673dd0 for this RuntimeCallableWrapper failed with
> the following error: The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.
> (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010108 (RPC_E_DISCONNECTED)). This is typically
> because the COM context 0x673dd0 where this RuntimeCallableWrapper was
> created has been disconnected or it is busy doing something else. Releasing
> the interfaces from the current COM context (COM context 0x673d18). This
> may cause corruption or data loss. To avoid this problem, please ensure
> that all COM contexts/apartments/threads stay alive and are available for
> context transition, until the application is completely done with the
> RuntimeCallableWrappers that represents COM components that live inside them.

My Code: **For FileUpload**

```
string filefullpath = null;
            try
            {
                string filepath = Server.MapPath("~/BulkUploadFile/");
                string filename = fuDatabaseFile.FileName;
                string filetype = Path.GetExtension(filename);
                string filenamewithoutextension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filepath);
                string append = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfffFFF");
                string newfilename = filenamewithoutextension + append + filetype;



                filefullpath = filepath + newfilename;

                fuDatabaseFile.SaveAs(filefullpath);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
```

Code for ExcelConnectivity:

```
FileUpload();
                string excelconnectionstring = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + FileUpload() + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;Persist Security Info=False";
                using (OleDbConnection excelcon = new OleDbConnection(excelconnectionstring))
                {
                    using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("", excelcon))
                    {
                        command.CommandText = "Select * from [Sheet1$]";
                        excelcon.Open();
                        using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            DataTable table = new DataTable();
                            table.Columns.Add("Name");
                            table.Columns.Add("EmpID");
                        }
                     }
                }
```